# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, centos7, pyyaml

I have a centos7 machine with python-2.7.5 installed as a default python.
For my work, I need 3.x version of python on the same machine, so I have installed python-3.6.8 and created a soft link where `/usr/bin/python` point to `/usr/bin/python3` with following command:

`sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

Now, for a sample python script, let's say: test.py, I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'` error when I am trying to `import yaml` in it.

test.py script is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""
Sample python script to import yaml.
"""

import yaml

print("Hello! Could you please help me resolve this?")
```

And the error is as below:

```
[cloud-user@xx.xx.xx.xx]$python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

I saw a couple of queries raised on stackoverflow and on github, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131804/importerror-no-module-named-yaml-ansible), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333654/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-yaml) and [this](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/291), but do not see any response that has resolved this issue.

As suggested on the links above, I have installed pyyaml using below command:

`sudo python3 -m pip install pyyaml` and `sudo pip3 install pyyaml` but I am still continue to get `ModuleNotFoundError` error.

Could anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Akshat Sharma

Comment: There could be more than just 2 Pythons. Are you sure `sudo python3` runs `/usr/bin/python3`? Are you sure `sudo pip3` runs `pip3` that uses `/usr/bin/python3`? You have to check paths (use `which`, for example `sudo which python3`), versions (`sudo pip3 --version`) and shebangs (`head -1 $(sudo which pip3)`).

Comment: Or maybe you just need to import the modul pyyaml instad of yaml ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+%27yaml%27

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333654/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-yaml)

Comment: @phd Thanks for your response. here are the output of commands:
`sudo which python3`
/bin/python3

`sudo which pip3`
/bin/pip3

`sudo pip3 --version`
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

`head -1 $(sudo which pip3)`
#!/usr/bin/python3

Comment: @Joe I did try installing pyyaml as mentioned the link, but it did not resolve the error.

Comment: @phd importing pyyaml does not help. 
could you help me setting up python3 ? Is the idea of creating a symlink `sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python` correct after installing python 3.x or there is something else that I need to setup for python3 to be the default python?

Comment: Please take a look at `import sys; sys.executable` Did you install the module in the correct place? Are you using a virtual environment, Jupyter, Anaconda?

Comment: @Joe I am not using any virtual env. Also, when I install any python module, for example ansible using yum, it is getting installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` instead of `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages` even though I have set python3 as defalut python using `alternatives`( it was suggested on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542690/how-to-set-python3-5-2-as-default-python-version-on-centos/61341505#61341505) ).

Comment: import sys; sys.executable?

Comment: @Joe 
[cloud-user@xxxx ~]$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python'

Comment: Ok, that's probably a python 2...

Comment: @Joe Okay, but is there any solution for this?

Comment: Coming here with the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Such issues occur when there are multiple distribution of python installed in your system.

Just run: **pip3 list** command and see whether you are able to see the package in the list. If not, you are not installing the PyYaml package at the correct location.

PS: also sometimes for normal user python is at different location and for sudo user, it is at different location. Check running the command without giving sudo.

Comment: What if you are able to see it in the list but still get the error?